# AWS step function state transition failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

[AWS step function execution guarantees](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/express-at-least-once-execution.html) tells that "The execution state is internally persisted on every state transition.".

What happens when the ProcessPayment lambda function succeeded but the state transition to UpdateCustomerAccount failed due to an internal AWS error?

I would appreciate to pointing me to the corresponding step function documentation.

[image: Step function workflow]

Answer (score 0):

Step Functions does not fail on state transitions. If there are issues, the scheduling of the next state might get delayed, but step functions will always eventually schedule and run the next state.

The work done by each state might fail, such as failing to complete the work, fail to send/receive request, etc, but there will never be an error due to a state transition failing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: _Step Functions does not fail on state transitions_

Why do you state this? Everything may fail. Would you please refer me to the corresponding AWS documentation?